# NSURLBookmarkCreationPreferFileIDResolution has no effect

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsurl

I'm trying to create a Bookmark that locates a file even after it's been moved or renamed.  Here I create & store a Bookmark for `~/Desktop/file.txt`:

```
- (void) writeBookmark {
    NSURL* urlToBookmark = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[@"~/Desktop/file.txt" stringByExpandingTildeInPath]] ;
    NSData* bookmarkData = [urlToBookmark bookmarkDataWithOptions:NSURLBookmarkCreationPreferFileIDResolution  includingResourceValuesForKeys:nil  relativeToURL:nil  error:nil ] ;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:bookmarkData forKey:@"bookmarkData"] ;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize] ;
}
```

And here I read the stored Bookmark:

```
- (void) readBookmark {
    NSData* bookmarkData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"bookmarkData"] ;
    NSURL* urlFromBookmark = [NSURL URLByResolvingBookmarkData:bookmarkData  options:0  relativeToURL:nil  bookmarkDataIsStale:nil  error:nil] ;
    NSLog(@"%@", [urlFromBookmark.path stringByAbbreviatingWithTildeInPath]) ;
}
```

I ran `writeBookmark` and `readBookmark` consecutively, and it worked as expected, logging `~/Desktop/file.txt`.

Then I moved file.txt from `~/Desktop` to `~/Music`, then ran `readBookmark`.  It worked as expected, logging `~/Music/file.txt`.

Finally, I created a new file at `~/Desktop/file.txt` and ran `readBookmark`.  Instead of logging `~/Music/file.txt` as expected, it logged `~/Desktop/file.txt`.  Shouldn't `NSURLBookmarkCreationPreferFileIDResolution` cause the NSURL to always point to the original file from which it was created, regardless of whether a different file exists at the original file's path?

I'm developing for OS X 10.8, not sandboxed.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem. A new file at the original location of the original (but now moved) file will make the resolution point to the new file, even though the new file has a different file ID.